# Selenium Facebook popup window not closing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am using **Selenium** to automate the process of retrieving Ronaldo's latest post updates from **Facebook** and sending them to my friend's Gmail. However, I am facing a challenge in overcoming the Facebook login popup window that appears when I navigate to the Facebook website.

[image: The image of the popup window]

I am using the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ch_opt = Options()
ch_opt.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=ch_opt)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/Cristiano/")

close_btn = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH,
    '//*[@id="mount_0_0_3b"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/i',
)
close_btn.click()
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

````
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mount_0_0_3b"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/i"}
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.188); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception```
````

Can someone please help me figure out how to fix this error and close the Facebook login popup window using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below xpath. Remember that "Close" should be in your language.
Xpath = //div[@role='button' and @aria-label='Close']